# How to get AUCTeX to automatically generate a`TeX-engine:luatex` file-variable directive upon creating a new .tex document?

Tags: auctex

Is there a way to cause AUCTeX to automatically generate the line

```
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
```

in a new `.tex` document as it does with other file-variables, such as `TeX-master`?

Comment: So you prefer a per-document setting rather than making luatex the default engine just for you? (I think this is a good way to go). Note that if you try to compile a document that loads fontspec package, AUCTeX will ask you to select a proper engine

Comment: @giordano: What do you mean by 'I think this is a good way to go'? That the per-document setting is a good way to go, or that making luatex the default engine just for me is a good way to go?

Comment: The former, because you don't rely on people's default options  :-)

Comment: With a recent version of AUCTeX, do `C-c C-m usepackage RET fontspec RET` in your .tex file and AUCTeX will ask you for an engine with completion incl. adding your choice to your file.

Comment: @giordano: But is there a way for AUCTeX to automatically generate the `TeX-engine:luatex` file-variable *upon the document's creation*, hence, before any `\usepackage{fontspec}` line has been written and before the file has been compiled? After all, `fontspec`, while strongly recommended for use in conjunction with luatex, [is not mandatory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338781).

Comment: Yes, I got your question (and provided an answer ;-), and yes, I know that `fontspec` is not mandatory (like it isn't mandatory to set any font with `pdftex`), but it's often used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code to your init file:

```lisp
(add-hook
 'find-file-hook
 (lambda ()
   (when (eq major-mode 'latex-mode)
     ;; Check if we are looking at a new or shared file.
     (when (or (not (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name)))
           (eq TeX-master 'shared))
       (add-file-local-variable
    'TeX-engine
    (intern (completing-read "Add TeX-engine with value: "
                 (mapcar 'car (TeX-engine-alist)) nil nil nil nil "default"))))
     (TeX-update-style t))))
```

This is inspired by how AUCTeX asks you for master file when you create a new file.

Comment: Thank you. And to set LuaTeX as the Emacs-wide default, the following line should be added to `.emacs`, right? `(setq-default TeX-engine 'luatex)`

Comment: Also: could you please modify your answer so that if I simply hit `Enter` in reply to the question `Add TeX-engine with value:` without specifying a value, the current default value (pdfTeX?) will be selected, or better yet, the `TeX-engine` file-variable won't get written at all, which is the current behavior?

Comment: I've updated the answer so that `default' is the default engine (also because it's slightly simpler than adding nothing with empty input).  BTW, you should also check out an autocompletion package like helm & Co ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, I've just noticed something. The `mode` file-variable is set automatically to `latex` regardless of the `TeX-engine` setting. Is this the correct behavior? To make the question more concrete, if my `.tex` document is written in the  LuaLaTeX dialect and I wish to compile it with the `luatex` program, is it enough to set the `TeX-engine` file-variable to `luatex` or will the fact that the `mode` file-variable is set to `latex` cause any trouble? Does the `mode` file-variable definition need to be deleted, or changed, say, to `lualatex`?

Comment: `latex-mode` is to distinguish between plain TeX, LaTeX, docTeX, ConTeXt, TeXinfo, see https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Modes-and-Hooks  It has nothing to do with the actual engine used ;-)  AUCTeX is one of the few editors I know that correctly keeps the language and the engine used separated: e.g., you can compile with luatex engine a plain TeX document.